# I'm trying to display different Divs related to what language type the user has clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 different flags "Eng" "Bulg" "Grece" and I have 2 Divs by Default the first Div "table" is FadedIn when "LinkButton17" is clicked but now I want to display the second Div "tableEng" if the user has clicked "Eng" or "Grece" before that so I tried this but it does not work. The second Div "tableEng" doesn't FadeIn if before that I have clicked "Eng" or "Grece"
LinkButton17 is inside Update Panel and has

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            sessionStorage.setItem('index', '1');
            $("#Eng , #Grece").click(function () { sessionStorage.setItem('index', '2'); });
            $("#Bulg").click(function () { sessionStorage.setItem('index', '1'); });
            $("#LinkButton17").click(function () {

                $("#text").html = ("");
                if (sessionStorage.getItem('index') == '1') {
                    $("#table").fadeIn(1000);
                    $("#tableEng").fadeOut(1000);
                }
                else {

                    $("#tableEng").fadeIn(1000);
                    $("#table").fadeOut(1000);
                }


            });
        });
    </script>
```

These OnClick events are server side and are changing some text on the webpage.
HTML:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Eng" style="position:absolute;top:1vh;left:88vw;width:24px;height:12px;border:1px solid black;" ImageUrl="~/Logos/Uk_union_flag.png" OnClick="Eng_Click"/>         
           <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Bulg" style="position:absolute;top:1vh;left:83vw;width:24px;height:12px;color:white;font-size:20px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;border:1px solid black;" ImageUrl="~/Logos/bulgeria-flag.gif" OnClick="Bulg_Click"/>  
           <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Grece" style="position:absolute;top:1vh;left:93vw;width:24px;height:12px;color:white;font-size:20px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;border:1px solid black;" ImageUrl="~/Logos/greece_flag.png" OnClick="Grece_Click"/>


<div id="table" style="position:absolute;left:22.5vw;width:55vw;top:90.333vh;height:auto;background-color:white;display:none;padding:5px;">
       <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
               bla bla bla
       </table>
```

```
<div id="tableEng" style="position:absolute;left:22.5vw;width:55vw;top:90.333vh;height:auto;background-color:white;display:none;padding:5px;">
     <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, remove inline styles from your code and create working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the ASP parts,
But from what I understand you simply want to toggle different content containers according to the language the user has chosen.

For that I've created a simple example using basic jQuery & css:

```js
//Sets a default language to be shown when the page loads
var chosenLang = "en";

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Makes sure all content blocks are hidden, then show the default one
  //Notice the 'data-lang' attributes in the html
  $("div.content>div").hide();
  $("div.content>div[data-lang=" + chosenLang + "]").show();

  //On click, simply change the chosen language and again - display the relevant content block accordingly 
  $("ul.flags>li").click(function() {
    $("div.content>div").hide();
    chosenLang = $(this).attr("data-lang");
    $("div.content>div[data-lang=" + chosenLang + "]").show();
  });

});
```

```css
.flags {
  list-style: none;
}
.flags li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 3px;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 15px;
}
.content > div {
  display: none; /*Hides all content blocks*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="flags">
  <li data-lang="en">International</li>
  <li data-lang="en">US</li>
  <li data-lang="gr">Greece</li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
  <div data-lang="en">
    English content goes here
  </div>
  <div data-lang="gr">
    Greek content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5myggL0/

If that doesn't work, please do create a working jsfiddle version of your code so that we can see what you had wrong.